# how to insert more than two variables into text PYTHON

Tags: python, variables, canvas, text

I have a problem with inserting two variables into text. Can you help me with that? Separation with comma or & does not help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time
a=7
cluster=10
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Ainalaiyn Task Manager")
window.geometry("1200x600+0+0")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width=200, height=200, bg="bisque", bd=5)
canvas1.pack(side="top", fill="both")
canvas1.create_text(10, 70, anchor="sw", fill="black",font="Times 15 italic", text="There is an upcoming task in %d days at %d cluster!" %a %cluster)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate strings and variables?  Does 'Text'+str(var) not work  or is it not allowed for some reason?

Comment: Hi, you should try to create the minimal example when asking a question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question here is about `"There is an upcoming task in %d days at %d cluster!" %a %cluster`, so that is actually the only part of your code which is relevant. You should not include various `tkinter`, `random` etc. in the question just because you have them in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these work (last one only > 3.6):

```
"There is an upcoming task in %d days at %d cluster!" % (a, cluster)
```

---

```
"There is an upcoming task in {0} days at {1} cluster!".format(a, cluster)
```

---

```
f"There is an upcoming task in {a} days at {cluster} cluster!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `somestring = "There is an upcoming task in %d days at %d cluster!" % (a, cluster)`
2. Or use format string. `somestring = "There is an upcoming task in {0} days at {1} cluster!".format(a, cluster)`

Comment: @Aigerim If an answer resolves your problem, you can click the check mark (✓) next to the answer to accept it. This indicates that you accept the answer, removing the question from the list of unanswered questions. Also, it increases the reputation of the person who answered, thus awarding them for invested effort. Once you have enough reputation, you will also be able to upvote or downvote any questions and answers.